# Looking for a list of aliases

Tags: networking, tcp, alias

All,

I have an IP address and I want to know all aliases within my organization that point to this IP. Is it possible?

For example I know the alias "TESTBOX" points to 119.119.119.119. 
How can by just knowing the IP come up with the "TESTBOX" ?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

You can try a reverse lookup on the IP address, but that will only show you the address that has been specifically allocated in the reverse DNS to that IP address.

Remember, aliases might exist only as an entry on a single machine's `hosts` file.  They might also exist in a DNS server on the other side of the planet.  However, if you're only interested in local DNS aliases, and your DNS servers allow zone transfers, then you can try listing every entry in every domain (eg. with `host -l xyzzy.bigcorp.com`) and searching the results for the IP address in question.